# $B/\hat{B}$ is integral over $A / \hat{p}$ when $B$ is integral over $A$ and $\hat{B} \cap A = \hat{p}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I know that if $B \supset A$ are two rings and $B$ is integral over $A$, then $\sigma(B)$ is integral over $\sigma(A)$ where $\sigma : B \to C$ is any hom into a third ring.

I want to use that fact to prove that if $\hat{p}$ is a prime ideal in $A$ and $\hat{B}$ lies above $\hat{p}$, or in other words $\hat{B} \cap A = \hat{p}$, then $B/\hat{B}$ is integral over $A/\hat{p}$.

I know that the following diagram commutes:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>{\iota}>> B\\
@V\pi_AVV @V\pi_BVV \\
A/\hat{p} @>{\iota^*}>> B/\hat{B}
\end{CD}
$$
where $\pi$'s are natural surjections, and $\iota$ is inclusion, and $\iota^*$ is induced by $\iota$.

---

So we take $\sigma = \pi_B$.  Then $\sigma(A) = \pi_B \circ \iota(A) = \iota^* \circ \pi_A(A)$.

But isn't $\iota^* \circ \pi_A(A) = B/\hat{B}$?

Comment: Why do you think that last equation is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is to prove that $B/\hat{B}$ is integral over $\iota^*(A/\hat{p})$.  Since $\pi_A$ is surjective, $\iota^*(A/\hat{p})=\iota^* \circ \pi_A(A)=\sigma(A)$. So since you know $\sigma(B)=B/\hat{B}$ is integral over $\sigma(A)$, you're done.  It is entirely irrelevant whether $\iota^* \circ \pi_A(A) = B/\hat{B}$.

In any case, the equation $\iota^* \circ \pi_A(A) = B/\hat{B}$ usually is not true, and I'm not sure why you think it is.  For example, if $A$ and $B$ are domains and $\hat{p}=\hat{B}=0$, then $B/\hat{B}$ is just $B$ and $\iota^* \circ \pi_A(A)$ is just $A$, so they are only equal if $A$ was all of $B$ to begin with.

Comment: I see, I forgot to put $A/ \hat{p}$ inside of $B/\hat{B}$.